# Create one executable from two or multiple python scripts

Tags: python, pandas, exe

I have to create a python .exe from two scripts(then using three scripts).
There's something I miss here I believe, I followed answers from similar questions but wasn't able to solve my problem.
In order to create an executable, I have created a new_script.py code with

```
import script1
import script2
```

Then followed this command in cmd

```
pyinstaller --onefile new_script.py
```

Running the new_script.py in the editor, both scripts are running but after creating the executable, only the first one is running(script1)

Please help me understand what is that I'm missing here, my python version is 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and got the following result:

file1.py

```
print("Hello from file1")
```

file2.py

```
print("Hello from file2")
```

main.py

```
import file1
import file2

input() # This line just waits for the users input (in order not to close the terminal after the prints)
```

I then ran the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

The folder "dist" was then generated (along with other files) which contains the file main.exe. When running this file, the following was printed:

```
Hello from file1
Hello from file2
```

I recommend you try to do this as well and if it's working you know it's something wrong with the code and not pyinstaller.

Comment: thank you. It is not working when converting into exe. Is there something else I should add in the scripts before creating main.py?

Comment: @isa if i'm understanding you correct, the problem is still that both prints are not showing?  Does it give you any type of error when creating the exe?, does it work if you just run the main.py?

Comment: no, just maximum recursion depth exceeded which I solve it by increasing the limit into the main.spec file. After the executable is being created, only the first script is running